# MKMapView how to know rotation angle?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, mkmapview

In iOS 7, an MKMapView can be rotated by the user (like in the Maps app).

I have overlays and to determine whether I can display them, I need to compute the zoom scale. In iOS 6, I used to do:

```
MKZoomScale zoomScale = self.mapView.bounds.size.width / self.mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
```

The problem is that **the result of this computation changes when the user rotates the map**, where as the actual zoom scale should be the same (the size of the overlays tiles is the same, it's just rotated).

So my problem is the following: **how to compute the *real* zoom scale that does not change when the user rotates the map** ? If I had the rotation angle, I could correct the "bias" but I could not find any property in MKMapView to have this angle.

A workaround would be to disable map rotation, but I want to keep this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a computed zoom scale, you can use the new `MKMapCamera` `altitude` property.  It won't change as the map rotates and I think it stays the same even if the user changes the map's pitch angle.

```
MKMapCamera *camera = self.mapView.camera;
CLLocationDistance altitude = camera.altitude;
if (altitude < 3000 && altitude > 1000) {
    // do something
}
```

If you still need to know the rotation angle, you can get that from the map camera too:

```
CLLocationDirection mapAngle = camera.heading;
```

Comment: Oh, missed this property! Thanks! After testing, the altitude does change with the pitch, but one can compensate by doing `alt = alt / cos(mapView.camera.pitch*M_PI/180.0)`

Comment: Ah, good math. Let me know if using the altitude like this works instead of zoom.